# gdb doesn't stop on breakpoint

Tags: c, gdb, shared-libraries, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug a shared library which run under [check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) in unit-testing scenario.
The shared library is statically linked (no `dlload`) and both the unit-testing application and the shared library are compiled with debugging symbols (`-g`)

In `gdb` I want to set a breakpoint in a function contained in the shared library.
I set a breakpoint successfully, but when it runs it just passes over the break-point.

**What I've tried already:**

I placed a `printf` in the shared library, it is printed out, so the function is actually called.

**Here's the Makefile I'm using for compilation:**

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC    = gcc
CFLAGS       = -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Iinclude
EXTRA_FLAGS  = -fPIC -shared
LIBFLAGS     = -fPIC -shared 
LDFLAGS      = -shared -pthread -lcheck
DEBUGFLAGS   = -O0 -D _DEBUG
RELEASEFLAGS = -O2 -D NDEBUG -combine -fwhole-program
TEST_LDFLAGS = -lcheck -lllist -Llib -Wl,-rpath $(OBJDIR)

OBJDIR  = lib
TARGET  = $(OBJDIR)/libllist.so
TEST_TARGET = starttest
SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.c)
HEADERS = $(shell echo inc/*.h)
TEST_SOURCES = $(shell echo tests/*.c)
TEST_OBJECTS = $(TEST_SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
PREFIX = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

all: $(TARGET) tests
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIBFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)


tests: $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $(TEST_TARGET) $(TEST_OBJECTS) $(TEST_LDFLAGS)

# Need a special rule to compile the lib to allow EXTRA_FLAGS
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    @echo [Compiling]: $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(TEST_OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS) *~ $(TARGET) $(TEST_TARGET)

runtests:
    ./$(TEST_TARGET)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know specifics of the `check` framework you are using, but some such frameworks execute code-under-test in a child process. If `check` does that, then your behavior is expected -- you are only debugging the parent process, but your code executes in a child.

You can easily confirm this guess: replace the `printf` in your code with `abort`. If GDB doesn't stop on `SIGABRT`, then my guess is likely correct, and you'll want to `(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child`.

Alternatively, read up on [multi-inferior debugging.](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html) You can ask GDB to debug both the parent and the child with `set detach-on-fork off` ([documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html)).

Comment: You're right, I solved the issue by using a debug option to turn-off forking in check framework. Thanks. - http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_4.html#No-Fork-Mode

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue because you can't debug C++ from within a Docker container by default. Docker blocks certain syscalls (eg. strace) and you'll need specifically whitelist them to allow gdb to work.

Start your container with:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined -v $(pwd):/mnt cpp-debug:0.0.1
```

Note: This enable EVERY syscall to be used within docker.

Summary of issue: https://blog.johngoulah.com/2016/03/running-strace-in-docker/

Walk through to debug C++ inside docker: https://leimao.github.io/blog/Debug-CPP-In-Docker-Container/